# How to put two password fields in a row at UserCreationForm of Django, or how to add my own html in UserCreationForm?

Tags: html, css, django-forms

I created a sign up form by extending Django's `UserCreationForm`. Since Django adds all HTMLs by default I can't put my own HTML in it, just to customize it a bit.

This is how my current signup form looks like:

[image]

you can see `password` and `password confirmation` are added one after another. I would like to show them side by side, something like this:

[image]

I don't know where to add my HTML to make it look like the one above, this is my `signup.html` here:

```
{% block content %}
<form action="." method="POST" class="signup">
    <h4 class="display-6 bg-secondary text-white p-3">Create your account</h4>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <input type="submit" value="Sign up" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
    <p class="display-6 bg-signup p-3">Have an account <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one answered my question within last 36 hours. Finally just now I find an answer to my own question. So I am answering my own question, maybe someone in the future read it and find it useful.

After adding my custom HTML and CSS I finally manage to show two password fields side by side like this:

[image]

I used [django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks) to achieve this result:
as you can see in above picture, two password fields are added side by side. Moreover, errors are shown as well.

this was the previous html form:

```
{% block content %}
<form action="." method="POST" class="signup">
    <h4 class="display-6 bg-secondary text-white p-3">Create your account</h4>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <input type="submit" value="Sign up" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
    <p class="display-6 bg-signup p-3">Have an account <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Now the HTML codes look like this one below, the code pretty much explains itself. So I don't feel to elaborate it. I used bootstrap 4.

```
{% block content %}
<div class="accountform">
    <form method="POST">
        <h4 class="display-6 text-white p-3">Create your account</h4>
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="alert alert-danger p-0" style="border:none;">
            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
            <span class="err">{{ error }}</span><br>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="id_username">Username</label>
            {% render_field form.username class='form-control' placeholder='John Doe' %}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="id_email">Email</label>
            {% render_field form.email class='form-control' placeholder='johndoe@email.com' %}
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="id_password1">Password</label>
                {% render_field form.password1 class='form-control' placeholder='****' %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="id_password2">Confirm Password</label>
                {% render_field form.password2 class='form-control' placeholder='****' %}
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Sign up" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        <p class="display-6 bg-signup p-3">Have an account <a href="{% url 'signin' %}">Sign In</a></p>
    </form>
</div>

</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

dont' forget to add `{% load widget_tweaks %}` at the top of your template.

Thanks